# Run Alpine on Raspberry PI 3 Model B+

Tags: linux, pi-3b+

I try to run my spare Raspberry PI 3 Model B+ with the most recent version of Alpine Linux (3.9.0). After I plugged everything in, HDMI, keyboard, LAN, SD Card and power, I don't get any reaction. After trying to select the input on my screen I get no signal and it searches for other signals. It seems like no HDMI signal is send, and only the red power LED is on. The activity LED stays off and it doesn't matter how long I keep it connected to the power it doesn't happen anything.

I get the same behavior if I connect the PI to the offical Raspberry PI touchscreen. I tried several suggestions from the forums but they didn't work.

The hardware is ok, it works with Raspbian.

Edit: Here are the links I tried:
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Classic_install_or_sys_mode_on_Raspberry_Pi
https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/6668
https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/5296
https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/7451

Comment: Where do you get your distro from? Do the docs say it's compatible with the 3b+?

Comment: @Dirk official Alpine website. They have a specific release for the Rasperrys and the 3B+ is compatible.

Comment: It would be good if you added relevant links to your question. Saves other users having to search or it.

Comment: @Dirk Check my edit.

Comment: No activity on the green led means either there is no SD card inserted, or the card is incorrectly formatted.

Comment: It is formatted the same way, I formatted it with Raspbian. I just replaced the files.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried several suggestions from the forums. Do you also tried the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)? It's a great collection of checks and solutions. Most boot problems can be solved with it.

Comment: Check my edit to see what I tried. The hardware is ok, it works with Raspbian.

Comment: @Knerd No link you presented points to `https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151`.

Comment: Yes, they don't help or don't apply.